# IOS html5 audio API can not play m4a converted by ffmpeg

Tags: ios, html, audio, ffmpeg, m4a

I'm using Html5 audio api play m4a on IOS
I converted mp3 to m4a by ffmpeg. here is the script

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -i ./Uploads/" + str(current) + ".mp3 -t 15 -c:a aac -b:a 64k ./Uploads/" + str(current) + "_lite.m4a
```

then I play the m4a by audio api on IOS. and I got the error

```
undefined:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
```

then a try mp3 mp4 format, works fine.

Is there a solution to resolve this error? Thank you very much!